# Android как получить данные из другого приложения?

Tags: java, android

Стоит цель: "получить данные о пульсе с другого приложения", речь идет о чужом приложении *[HBand 2.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.timaimee.hband&hl=en_US)*. p.s. возник такой вопрос, т.к. не смог заполучить эти данные напрямую с браслета, зашифровано

Программно это можно сделать из другого приложения, что-то вроде обратиться к такому приложению и запросить информацию о пульсе?

Видел запуск программ через `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("программа");`, однако смогу ли я через него получить нужную информацию?

И есть ли другие способы вытащить эту информацию из программы?

Comment: Добрый день!
Не подскажите, было ли найдено Вами решение?
Столкнулся с тем же вопросом, как и Вы
Заранее спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Comment: @ВалентинГришин ниже был дан ответ от Barmaley, к сожалению в моём случае, чужое приложение ни каким из перечисленных способов не распространяет свои данные, поэтому получить не удалось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько способов получения информации с чужого приложения:

1) Классика жанра: приложение наружу выставляет свое `Activity`, который можно запустить через `Intent` и получить результат работы через `startActivityForResult()` - минус такого подхода в том, что при запуске требуется вмешательство юзера. По сути это православный способ запуска внешнего приложения, нечто типа: `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

2) Другая классика: приложение публикует свои данные через `ContentProvider` - для этого провайдер данных должен быть декларирован на стороне чужого приложения как `exported` - надо смотреть манифест приложения. Если есть такой провайдер, то вы тупо берете данные через `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query()`

3) возможно приложение публикует свои данные через `Broadcast` - в этом случае выставляете `BroadcastReceiver` и ловите бродкасты чужого приложения - опять надо смотреть манифест

4) Возможно что приложение выставляет `Service` с флагом `exported` - в этом случае читаете данные из сервиса

5) Есть еще один редко используемый вариант, когда приложение объявляет свои данные `shared` - речь идет о внутренней БД/файлах приложения:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.shared"
    android:sharedUserLabel="@string/sharedUserLabel"
    ...>
```

6) Далее начинается уже хакинг, но это уже неинтересно.

В общем выкачайте приложение, расковыряйте его манифест - там уже все будет видно что он может, а чего нет.

Comment: `android:exported="false"`, кажется всё плохо :(

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно почитать про 4 способ? Чтение из сервиса

Comment: Покажите manifest приложения - попробую подумать

Comment: (HBand 2.0) https://yadi.sk/d/FDXBE6Codcypig , (GoHeart) https://yadi.sk/d/HatXHaxHMYY5tQ

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос  - Yandex диск закрыт (не только у меня очевидно)

Comment: Проверил, переходил по ссылкам без авторизации(без аккаунта), все доступно

Comment: Речь идет о том, что корпоративный файерволл режет коннект к YD :)

Comment: (GoHeart) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tQQWcK8_PupC1vkeV4jQ2G2B4iE87LDK?usp=sharing , (HBand) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1annxtBbtp6XwfZxdq5Vkm8Cx12fBHxm6?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Система Андроид старается разграничивать доступ к данным различных приложений.Получить легальным способом информацию из другого приложения можно только если эта программа сама ее предоставляет. Возможно, в приложении HBand 2.0 реализована передача широковещательных сообщений по системе, то вы можете разработать приемник broadcast receiver, который будет слушать эти сообщения и обрабатывать их. Также это приложение может реализовывать contnent provider, для обеспечения к своим данным доступа из других приложений.